# linux command for finding a substring and moving it to the end of line

Tags: linux, substring, edit

I need to read a file line by line in Linux, find a substring in each line, remove it and place it at the end of that line.

Example:

Line in the original file:

```
a,b,c,substring,d,e,f
```

Line in the output file:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,substring
```

How do I do it with the Linux command? Thanks!

Comment: Will it always be comma-separated?

Comment: Can be tab separated too, I just used an .csv file as an example. In this case, I move ",substring" to the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/substring/{ s///; s/$/substring/;} '
```

will handle a fixed substring.  Note that if substring begins with a `,`, this handles your example case well.  If the substring is not fixed but may be a general regular expression:

```
sed 's/\(substring\)\(.*\)/\2\1'
```

If you are looking for general csv parsing, you should rephrase the question.  (It will be difficult to apply this solution to find a fixed string at the start of a line if you are thinking of the input as comma separated fields.)

Comment: I don't think this handles the commas in their example string.

Comment: Is there a solution to a generalized problem like to specify a separator (tab, comma, consecutive spaces, etc.), then remove the content from the N-th position and insert to the M-th position? A recommendation of good book for a Linix newbie would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use perl's command line to do such regex tasks - perl is powerful enough to cover awk and sed in most of my usages, and both available in windows and linux, it is just easy and handy to me, so the solution in perl would be like:

```
perl -ne "s/^(.*?)(?:(?<comma>,)(?<substr>substring)|(?<substr>substring)(?<comma>,))(?<right>.*)$/$1$+{right}$+{comma}$+{substr}/; print" input.txt > output.txt
```

or a simpler one:

```
perl -lpe "if(s/(,substring|substring,)//){ s/$/,substring/ }" input.txt > output.txt
```

**input.txt**

> substring,a,b,c,d,e,f
>   a,b,c,substring,d,e,f
>   a,b,c,d,e,f,substring
>   substring,a
>   a,substring
>   substring
>   a

**output.txt**

> a,b,c,d,e,f,substring
>   a,b,c,d,e,f,substring
>   a,b,c,d,e,f,substring
>   a,substring
>   a,substring
>   substring
>   a

You can edit based on your actual input:

- If there are any space between words and commas
- If you are using tab as separator

Some explanation of the command line:

- use perl's -n -e options: -n means process the input line by line in a loop; -e means one line program in the command line
- use perl's -l -p options: -l means process multilines; -p means always print
- The one line program is just a regex replacement and a print
- (?:pattern) means group but don't capture the match
- (?<comma>) is a named group, you then need to use $+{comma} hash to access it